# How to run JS files on specific page

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
<body class="home">
  content
</body>
```

And then I have:

```
<script src="abs.js"></script>
<script src="abse.js"></script>
<script src="abses.js"></script>
```

I have these scripts in head and they are running on all pages. How I can run them on ".home" page only?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Can you edit JS files or you want a solution in html page?

Comment: Hm, the problem looks more specific than I though.

I am using this client carousel, where are 3 external scripts. [link]https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/adding-an-infinite-client-logo-carousel-to-your-website.stml 

When I use these scripts on my page, the carousel is working but slider and price filter stop working. 

So I think, it's possible to run the script for <div id="nameoftheid"> only?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem by writing a function and load scripts by checking whether the url is home page url or not. Check following code, it will helpful to you.

**Note:** Change website url to yours from **/home/sys3028/Desktop/**

```js
/* loading scripts */
        loadingScripts();

        /* written by christyram99 */
        /* used to load scripts for specific page */
        function loadingScripts() {
            /* getting url of current page */
            var url = window.location.pathname;
            if (url == "/home/sys3028/Desktop/home.html") { /* checking whether the current page is home page or not */
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = "1.js";
            } else if (url == "/home/sys3028/Desktop/login.html") { /* checking whether the current page is login page or not */
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = "2.js";
            } else if (url == "/home/sys3028/Desktop/contact.html") { /* checking whether the current page is contact page or not */
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = "3.js";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you but I realized that's not solving my problem, so I ask you about one thing if you don't mind.

It's possible to run these 3 external script file for .class or #id only? Not for one specific page but for one div only?

I can target the div in JS but don't know how to add and run these scripts for it.

Thanks :-)

Comment: You can call the div's by class names also. Just replace **#something** to **.something**. You can select div's from jQuery by $("#somethinganother") and apply operations that you need. Is this clarifies your doubt or not? If is not just put another comment.

Comment: See my site [link]https://www.psimafie.cz/ 

If you use developer console you can see that some functions don't work because of external JS files from carousel [link]http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

If you want to click on next slider photo it doesn't work, if you want to use filter there: [link]https://www.psimafie.cz/chovatelske-potreby-pro-psy/ it doesn't work too, because of the JS files.

So I think that I run this scripts from slick to <div id="loga"> only but don't know how. If it's even possible.

Comment: make sure that you was included bootstrap.min.js before jquery.js loaded. I think the error because missing some js files to load.

Comment: I think the problem is because of the external carousel. If I remove the links to js files, slider and price filter working nice. If I add these files before </body> the slider and filter don't work.

I don't have permissions to edit some core files, I just can adding CSS/JS code to <head> and <body>.

Comment: Try to add files in the head. Some times the error will be gone if the functions are depend on the another js files.

Answer (score 1):

An HTML answer would be to only include them in the header of the homepage and remove the scripts from the other pages

Comment: Hm, the problem looks more specific than I though.

I am using this client carousel, where are 3 external scripts. [link]https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/adding-an-infinite-client-logo-carousel-to-your-website.stml 

When I use these scripts on my page, the carousel is working but slider and price filter stop working. 

So I think, it's possible to run the script for <div id="nameoftheid"> only?